# shell script for grabbing data and subtracting

Tags: bash, sed

Players from game A and B:

```
 wget --output-document=- http://runescape.com/title.ws 2>/dev/null \
    | grep PlayerCount \
    | head -1l \
    | sed 's/^[^>]*>//' \
    | sed "s/currently.*$/$(date '+%r %b %d %Y')/" \
    | cut -d">" -f 3,4 \
    | sed 's/<\/span>//'
```

Output: `111,048 people 10:43:54 PM Feb 22 2013`

Players from game B:

```
wget --output-document=- http://oldschool.runescape.com/ 2>/dev/null | grep "people playing"
```

Output: `There are currently 42823 people playing!`

I want to figure how many play Game A, but I am not so sure how to take the numbers you get from both of those outputs, and subtract them and output them in the same format like this:

```
`111,048 people 10:43:54 PM Feb 22 2013`
```

Comment: Once you get the numbers into variables, use `(($a - $b))` to subtract them.

Comment: Thanks. Just don't know a clue how trim and store just the numbers then display it again :(

Comment: You said you were stuck on the math part. It looks to me like you have a handle on how to use sed to pull apart strings.

Comment: Well hm. I guess I was wrong, the math part is okay. I did have help with the very very first script there using sed. I'm trying best I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh

URL1=http://runescape.com/title.ws
tot=`wget  -qO- $URL1  | grep -i PlayerCount | cut -d\> -f4 | cut -d\< -f1 | sed -e's/,//'`
URL2=http://oldschool.runescape.com
b=`wget -qO- $URL2| grep "people playing" | awk '{print $4}'`
a=`expr $tot - $b`
echo "$a people `date '+%r %b %d %Y'`"
```

... if you want commas do this add these line to the script ...

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
a_with_comma=`echo $a | awk "{printf \"%'d\n\", \\$1}"`
echo "$a_with_comma people `date '+%r %b %d %Y'`"
```

Comment: Wow you made it look easy. Is there a way to add a comma in the numerical result? I am OCD :(

Comment: I don't think there's an easy way to add commas to numbers. You'll have to write a loop that picks apart the number in groups of 3 digits.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand everything except that part. Will try to learn that bit.

Comment: Gaaaa, my eyes bleed.

Comment: @tripleee so where's you ingenious solution?

Answer (score 3):

```
total=$(wget --output-document=- http://runescape.com/title.ws 2>/dev/null |
        sed -n '/PlayerCount/{s/^[^0-9]*<span>\([0-9,]*\).*/\1/;s/,//g;p;q;}')
gameb=$(wget --output-document=- http://oldschool.runescape.com/ 2>/dev/null | 
        sed -n '/people playing/{s/There are currently \([0-9]*\) people playing!/\1/;p;q;}')
gamea=$(($total - $gameb))
```