# Grabbing text from html source

Tags: shell, unix, wget

```
#!/bin/sh

URL1=http://runescape.com/title.ws
tot=`wget  -qO- $URL1  | grep -i PlayerCount | cut -d\> -f4 | cut -d\< -f1 | sed -e's/,//'`
URL2=http://oldschool.runescape.com
b=`wget -qO- $URL2| grep "people playing" | awk '{print $4}'`
a=`expr $tot - $b`
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
a_with_comma=`echo $a | awk "{printf \"%'d\n\", \\$1}"`
echo "$a_with_comma people `date '+%r %b %d %Y'`"
```

This grabs 2 numbers from URL1 and URL2 and subtracts URL1 from URL2. Trying to get the "48,877 Players Online Now" from http://www.runescape.com/title.ws (URL1)

URL2 works fine I just can't get URL1.

Comment: That's hideous coding.

Comment: maybe it is time to break down and just write a Perl script : http://lwp.interglacial.com/ch06_01.htm

Comment: Brief googling suggests that Runescape has an API for this, so you should probably be using that instead. Some of the comments I saw alleged that useful parts are undocumented, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change ...

```
tot=`wget  -qO- $URL1  | grep -i PlayerCount | cut -d\> -f4 | cut -d\< -f1 | sed -e's/,//'`
```

... to ...

```
 tot=`wget  -qO- $URL1 | grep -i playercount | cut -d\> -f5 | cut -d\< -f1 | sed -e's/,//'`
```

... that is if you are in a hurry. Otherwise you might want to follow tripleee's advice.  Who knows you might get an award from the ACM :-)

Comment: Reason I wanted it the way it is, is because I can run this as a batch file in one click.

Comment: It looks like the content of URL changed slightly.  This approach is prone to these types of errors.  Anyways you can change `cut -d\> -f4` to `cut -d\> -f5` and your script should work.

Comment: what does -f4 and -f5 changed do? (i had help writing this)

Comment: Yes I was the one that helped you. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15036901/shell-script-for-grabbing-data-and-subtracting/15037092#15037092) remember :). Anyways, the content from URL1 has an extra `<span>` html tag now.  So you need to get field 5, `-f5`, instead of field 4, `-f 4`.

Comment: `-f` or `--field=int`. `-f` stands for field.  See `man cut`.

Comment: It means they changed the HTML so that it now has more occurrences of the character `>` before the data you want than they used to have.  This is why screen-scraping is a dubious solution at best.  You end up figuring out what changed and why that causes your code to break, over and over again.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick attempt at refactoring the original into just two `awk` instances, to get rid of most of the contortions.

```
#!/bin/sh

#URL1=http://runescape.com/title.ws
#tot=$(wget -qO- "$URL1" | awk 'tolower($0) ~ /playercount/ {
#    # Trim anything after this expression
#    gsub(/<\/span> Players Online Now<\/span>.*/, "")
#    # From the remainder, trim anything up through last tag close
#    gsub(/.*>/, "")
#    # Should be left with a number.  Remove any thousands separator
#    gsub(/,/, "")
#    # Should have a computer-readable number now.  Print it
#    print }')
URL0='http://www.runescape.com/c=eWHvvLATbvs/player_count.js?varname=iPlayerCount&callback=jQuery17201610493347980082_1378103074657&_=1378103197632'
tot=$(wget -qO- "$URL0" | awk -F '[()]' '{ print $2 }'

URL2=http://oldschool.runescape.com
wget -qO- "$URL2" | awk -v tot=$tot -v fmt="%'d people " '
    /people playing/ { printf(fmt, tot-$4 )}'
date '+%r %b %d %Y'
```

The processing for `URL1` should be somewhat more robust now, as it looks for a `span` followed by `Players Online Now`.  They could change the formatting of the page at any time in such a way that this breaks again, of course.  Thus, it would probably be even better to use a JSON API if they offer one.  (Brief googling suggests this exists, but is undocumented.  The main documentation seems to be at http://services.runescape.com/m=rswiki/en/Grand_Exchange_APIs but this has nothing about summary player stats.)

The comments are not strictly necessary, of course.  They should help you figure out what to change if the page's source changes again, so it's not a good idea to trim them, unless you learn Awk well enough that you don't need them.

*EDIT:* Updated to use the JSON API for the total player count -- this should be a lot more robust, and a lot simpler, too.  I left the original code commented out just in case.

Comment: looks like crap to me. :P

Comment: I use the grand exchange api for item prices (this is a game btw). as for player count I can only find this

http://www.runescape.com/c=eWHvvLATbvs/player_count.js?varname=iPlayerCount&callback=jQuery17201610493347980082_1378103074657&_=1378103197632

but that only applies to both games they have combined. as in my little script I subtract them out so it doesnt help much.

Comment: Using the API also means you download a lot less to get the tiny bit of information you want, so the game owners will probably like you better for using this approach, too.

Comment: Now that link I posted needs to get changed in order for the player count to be refreshed (i use it with epoch). Does that need it in this case as well?